# Bitcoin QT using the terminal

Tags: bitcoin-core

I am trying to compile bitcoin qt and I am getting these errors:

```
No targets specified and no makefile found.Stop.

user@localhost:~/bitcoin/src$ ./configure --with-qt
bash: ./configure: No such file or directory

user@localhost:~/bitcoin/src$ make -j8
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop.
```

I'm using Mint, not sure if there are different commands specifically for Mint.

Comment: Did you run ./autogen.sh first? Also, you are in the wrong directory. You should be in ~/bitcoin

Comment: I am following this instructions

Comment: If you are not already doing so, I think should carefully read the file `~/bitcoin/doc/build-unix.md` which explains how to install the required dependencies as well as the build process itself.

Comment: Thanks Sven, Yes the install has work, though not sure how lol.  But it looks very different from the old version.  I was just going through the folders and cant find the wallet dat,   Any help here would be very much appreciated.   Its pretty cool only 217 weeks to go.

Comment: Hi Nick, no i did not, the installation work with just this commonds:  ~/bitcoin/qmake-qt4 -makefile -Wall USE_QRCODE=1
make.

Comment: My other problem now is that i cant find the wallet dat.  I know that its a hidden file and I have checked in all folder, cant see it, has it changed name?

Comment: @Rosanna your `wallet.dat` file is located in the `~/.bitcoin` directory. Other files of interest in this directory are `debug.log` and `bitcoin.conf`

Comment: Hi Sven, ok, i have, home, bitcoin, when i double click on bitcoin i dont see the wallet file even when i click show hidden file.   I previously remove bitcoin wallet  as i was changing into mint, i took a back up of the old wallet dat. file.   I notice that even though i had remove the bitcoin wallet, now that it is open and doing that sync thing, it is showing my old transactions.   I think that reason why i dont see the wallet is because i had deleted it,  Does this mean that, i can just put the back up wallet dat. if so, do i need to wait until its finish the sync thing.  many thanks

Comment: @Rosanna The `.bitcoin` directory is not the same as the `bitcoin` directory. It is a hidden directory. From your mention of 'double click' it seems that you are accessing your file system via some GUI (as opposed to command lines on a terminal window). Look in the menu somewhere, there should be an option 'Show Hidden Files'.

Comment: Hi Sven, yes i found it, but my problem now is that hard drive is too small lol, so needing to upgrade hard before i can do anymore with the bitcoin wallet.

Comment: Type `cd ..` and try again.

Answer (score 1):

Type these commands inside bitcoin source root folder:

1) ./autogen.sh

2) ./configure

3) make

4) make install

Then you can call Bitcoin-qt simply typing the command `bitcoin-qt` from your terminal. If you provide the `make install` command as suggested in step 4 you can run both Qt and daemon from any path.

Answer (score 0):

The correct `configure` command is `./configure --with-gui=qt5` or `--with-gui=qt4` or `--with-gui=auto` if you're not sure.

You can always see what configure flags are supported with `./configure --help`.